# Multiple SQL instances on the same server and how to manage TempDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, instance

Probably a bizarre approach but I don't really have much say in the setup.
We have a large server deployed in Azure and the plan is to get 16 separate instances on this machine.  We plan on using the large D: (temp storage for the tempDB files). The usual PS script is installed on startup to create the relevant directory and SQL is on a delayed startup. The first instance has been created with TempDB on the C:\ (will be moving later once all instances are ready).

The issue is, when the 16 instances are created we will end up with 128 tempDB files (8 per instance).  The server will be literally minimal usage.  So hardly 50 users.  It's a development machine that has divided instances for the development work being carried out on it.

Can I potentially modify the script to create 16 folders on start up and set each instance to write to the dedicated folder so for example:

D:\TempDB\Instance1\8 files

D:\TempDB\Instance2\8 files

Or would just having all the 128 files in the root be OK?

(Setup = SQL Server 2016 SP2, WS-2016)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just install a single instance that hosts all the databases of all of yours instances? Management of 16 instances on one server sounds like a nightmare to me, especially with distribution of resources.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - I have no control over the development's team choice of platform unfortunately.  But all 128 files in the same folder causes no reason for concern? (something that is OK?)

Comment: @J.D - Unfortunately not.   Each instance is actually a test candidate  So 3 env's per candidate (ENV1, ENV2, ENV3) and then 5 clients.  Last instance is for other purposes. p.s. totally agreed on 16 instances being a total headache.

Comment: @dqnet Agreed with Aaron on storing all the TempDB files in the same folder for better management when you need to compare file size, etc. But perhaps name them slightly different to identify which instance they belong to. I still don't follow your use case or how it warrants 16 instances though. Why would a single test candidate need 3 separate instances?

Comment: Sorry brain stil waking up, so you have 5 test candidates, and basically a DEV / STAGING / PROD type of setup per test candidate I suppose? Is what you're testing dependent on the instances themselves being configured differently, if not, why do they need to be separate instances?

Comment: @J.D. - spot on.  Yes, each client has a specific set of databases, specific set of requirements and we need to adjust performance based on instances.  So renaming the TempDB files would be the best way to go?

Comment: @dqnet Yea I'd say at least adding an identifier to the start of each file name for which instance it belongs to might prove helpful one day. Just curious, generally speaking, what kinds of instance level settings are you testing?

Comment: Don't put files in the root of the drive as then you are unable to use folders to set ACLs

Comment: @J.D. - Perfect - yep, I will suffix it with the InstanceID.  Memory Allocation is one thing, One Instance down and One Instance up is another requirement, specific connection strings for the developers, etc.   Not many but enough to justify according to them.

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64 - why would you need ACL's on the TempDB folder in general? The files will all be in the the D:TempDB   folder  not D*.*

Comment: Thumbs up @AaronBertrand